# PHP Using Select Value To Set Variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm working in Wordpress here.

In the posts page I have a dropdown list of values:

```
<select name='imagesize'>
<option value='200x200'>200 x 200</option>
<option value='300x300'>300 x 300</option>
<option value='400x400'>400 x 400</option>
<option value='500x500'>500 x 500</option>
</select>
```

I have a button:

```
<a class="button" href="http://www.example.com/???">Click</a>
```

I want to replace the "???" with the value that is currently selected in the list when the user hits the button.

Any ideas how I can do this? Ajax?

Comment: You don't need PHP, you want JavaScript/jQuery to change the href value on the select onChange event.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a form submit button to submit the form. If you use a link you will need to run some javascript first to modify the link on the fly to append your information.

```
<form action="yourPHP.php" method="post">

<select name='imagesize'>
<option value='200x200'>200 x 200
<option value='300x300'>300 x 300
<option value='400x400'>400 x 400
<option value='500x500'>500 x 500
</select>

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Then in your PHP code, access it via:

```
<?php
    $yourImageSize="";
    if(isset($_POST["imagesize"]))
    {
        $yourImageSize=$_POST["imagesize"];
    }
    echo "Your image size is: ".$yourImageSize."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: No reliance on Javascript (or jQuery *yea!*), this is the better solution.  Minor point, but I'd pass values through `method="get"` and then refer to `$_GET` in the PHP code -- but I'll admit that is largely just style.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name='imagesize' id='imagesize'>
<option value='200x200'>200 x 200</option>
<option value='300x300'>300 x 300</option>
<option value='400x400'>400 x 400</option>
<option value='500x500'>500 x 500</option>
</select>
<a class="button" id="click_btn" href="http://www.example.com/???">Click</a>
```

you should add some javascript before the  element :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#imagesize").change(function(){
        $("#click_btn").attr("href","http://www.example.com/"+$("#imagesize").val())；
    });
</script>
```